# Python list attribute error

Tags: python, list, dictionary, attributes

I have a file called con.dat. I want to read the content of this file to search for a pattern. If the pattern is found, it then prints the message to the console.

con.dat

```
- file: /app.log
  pattern: "ERROR"
  message: "Error in App"
```

I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

my test.py code is as follows:

```
import yaml
import re

with open("con.dat","r") as f:
    triggers = yaml.load(f)

for filename in triggers.keys():
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        for line in f:
            trigger_info = triggers(filename)
            if re.search(trigger_info["pattern"],line):
                print("match found in line{0} for pattern{1}")
                format(line,trigger_info["pattern"])
```

I know my error related to triggers.keys(): but I am not sure the issue. I am new to python. Can someone guide me on how I should correct this error?

btw - my app.log file does contain a line with 'ERROR: blah blah blah' for testing

Comment: `triggers.keys()`: it seems that `triggers` is not a `dictionary` but a `list`. Lists, do not have the `keys()` attribute.

Comment: change line to `for filename in triggers:`, it should work

Comment: How do I make triggers a dictionary instead of a list?

Comment: changing line to for filename in triggers: causes a TypeError: expected str, bytes or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, 'triggers' is a list of dictionaries:

```
import yaml
import re

with open("con.dat","r") as f:
    triggers = yaml.load(f)

for entry in triggers:
    with open(entry["file"], "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.search(entry["pattern"], line):
                print("match found")
```

Answer (score 0):

triggers.keys(): it seems that triggers is not a dictionary but a list. Lists, do not have the keys() attribute.